# What pepper is used in Sriracha sauce?

Tags: sauce, spicy-hot

I am a great fan of hot sauces. Usually, they advertise what pepper they are using.

I cannot find that type of information on the Sriracha bottle I have at home. The only information I have is "chili".

What is the pepper use in that recipe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sriracha_sauce_(Huy_Fong_Foods)) they use red jalapenos.

Comment: Doh! I didn't even consider looking through their wikipedia page. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Huy Fong Sriracha Sauce is made with a specific variety of red jalapeños which, at this point, [is grown only for them](http://www.latimes.com/business/la-fi-himi-sriracha-farmer-20150315-story.html).

Note that this is different from traditional Thai sriracha, which is made fruitier and less hot peppers [like the goat pepper](http://thaitheparos.com/srirajapanich/faq.php?lang=_en).  If you haven't had this, I recommend picking up a bottle to keep alongside your Huy Fong, it's quite different tasting.

Non-traditional sriracha sauces, now made all over the world, may be made of any red, fleshy, hot pepper you can imagine. There's even a few green ones.